# Ruby Struggling including/requiring relative modules

Tags: ruby

I am reading this guide for programming Ruby:
https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/ruby_tutorial/modules

I wrote it out exactly as they recommended, and placed both files("Greeter.rb", "Person.rb") in the same folder.

Here are the files:

**Greeter.rb**:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
module Greeter
    def greet
        puts "Hello!"
    end
end
```

**Person.rb**:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class Person
    include Greeter
end

alice = Person.new
alice.greet
```

I get the following error when trying to run "ruby Person.rb":

```
Person.rb:4:in `<class:Person>': uninitialized constant Person::Greeter (NameError)
        from Person.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I  tried looking up the error, as well as how to load relative path modules,
and so on.

I've tried using include, require, as well as require_relative(which didn't seem to work).

The ruby version is "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]"

How do I resolve this error and get the demonstration to work?

Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` and `require_relative` load the code in the specified file and execute it. In order for Greeter to exist in `Person.rb` you need to `require` the file in which Greeter is defined. `require`s should usually go at the top of the file, not inside a class or method.

`include` takes the methods in the given module and adds them to the class in which you called `include`. But you can't `include Greeter` if you haven't `require`d the file in which it's defined.

In other words, you need both `require` (or `require_relative`) and `include`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require_relative "./Greeter.rb"

class Person
  include Greeter
end

alice = Person.new
alice.greet
```

In Ruby, classes and modules are objects like any other. You can't tell Ruby to do something with an object if the code that defines the object hasn't been run. `require` is what tells Ruby to load and run the code that defines Greeter, and `include`, in this case, is what tells Ruby to use that object.

Here's another way to think about it. Suppose you have these two files:

#### constants.rb

```
Message = "Hello, world!"
```

#### greet.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts Message
```

You probably wouldn't be surprised that `greet.rb` raises a NameError that says `uninitialized constant Message.`. We defined `Message` in another file that `greet.rb` doesn't know about. We have to tell Ruby to load it first:

#### greet2.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative "./constants.rb"
puts Message
```

Running `greet2.rb` will now print the message "Hello, world!"

The only difference between your Greeter and my Message is that Greeter is a module and Message is a string.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Now to carefully look over why.

If I understood correctly, the include assumes you already have the Greeter. Does this mean I can include the same module multiple times but only as long as I loaded it with require/require_relative first? Kinda like a snippet?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've updated my answer with some additional info that will hopefully help you understand.